# How to know that WINDOW.LOCATION load url

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, safari

I need to check if iPhone Safari support specific url (lppn://playnow - that url will run Texas Poker application if its already installed) if url does not supported i want to run other link (application page in AppStore).

Are WINDOW.LOCATION return false if it can not load uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location` won't return false, however you can use AJAX for this.

If jQuery is relevant, it's matter of one or two lines of code (AJAX call to the page, handle the onerror event) otherwise you'll have to build it yourself, but it's still possible.

Comment: @Guy ashamed to admit that I didn't research enough before answering.. while it *is* possible with AJAX, it requires server side "proxy" for the cross domain request - still matter of few lines, but can't be done with pure client side script. Up for @Pavel to decide if it's valid option and I can give some example.